If a conclusion logically follows from premises that are true in the world, will the conclusion also be true of the world?
If a set of premises is true in the world, and we rigorously apply logic to those premises to reach a conclusion, will that conclusion necessarily also be true of the world? If so, does this imply that (deductive) logic is an inherent feature of the world, even prior to the existence of humans or minds?
Is the universe metaphysically "obliged" to comply with (deductive) logic?
Furthermore, could there be multiple valid forms of logic (logical pluralism)? If so, which specific form of logic, if any, is "respected" or aligned with the way the world operates? Does the world favor one logic (e.g., deductive) over another (e.g., abductive or inductive), or are different logics applicable in different contexts?

I was inspired to ask this by this answer to Was logic invented or discovered?
Related: What is the difference between implication and causality?
Related: If physics can be reduced to mathematics (and thus to logic), does this mean that (physical) causation is ultimately reducible to implication?
Related: Is it possible to simulate a reality like ours using other logic than classical logic?

It is not as simple as logic "aligning with the world". You also need mathematics, physics and practical procedures to relate your physics to what is "in the world". It is only this conglomerate as a whole that "aligns with the world", not logic on its own. One can pick any expressive enough logic and then develop the rest accordingly to be so "aligned". The current variant we have is mostly based on classical logic, but intuitionistic and other variants have been explored as well.

I think that the converse: "If something is true then it logically followed from premises which are true" is a strong form of Determinism.

@Him I added two tags inspired by your reference.

By "rigorously" do you mean "correctly" as opposed to "in an exacting and thorough manner"? One may be exacting and thorough and still make a mistake.

@gs Yes, I mean correctly/optimally according to the rules of the given logic.

@gs In other words, if you play perfectly according to the game rules of the given logic, will reality necessarily match your conclusions?

"If a conclusion logically follows from premises..." means that the conclusion is TRUE in every circumstance where all premises are TRUE.

@MauroALLEGRANZA But that's question begging. We know that the conclusion can be derived mechanistically following step by step the rules of the formal logical system (i.e., following an algorithm essentially), but how do we know that it must be true in the real world? How do we know that the algorithm necessarily produces real-world truths?

That is the definition. Logic is formal: "if every x is A, then c is A". If every man is Mortal, then Socrates is Mortal. The first one is the "general" logical law, the second one is "applied" to our world.

@Him Does that get you to determinism at all?  Can't you just say "If P, then Q or R.  P, therefore Q or R."? That example wouldn't be deterministic at all. There's a true statement, but it still leaves multiple possibilities.  I think that would only entail strong determinism if your logic also didn't allow concepts like "or".

From a practical perspective, this is what experiments are all about. Identify the conclusions that logically follow from a theory, and if we can show that they're false, the theory (as stated) must also be false by modus tollens.

I think the statement I made is more like: "For all P, (if P then (there exists Q such that ((Q!=P) and Q and (if Q then P))))".  I think one may need to say something about temporal or causal relationships between Q and P for that statement to be identical to determinism, depending on which flavour of determinism one is interested in.  Basically, though, the statement that everything has a direct cause is more-or-less just determinism.

@Him I'm pretty sure that's still missing a big part of determinism.  We can look at a series of events and find direct causes, but that is working backwards compared to determinism. I dont see how being able to assign causes to effects implies that a cause can only result in one possible set of effects, for example in QM it can be represented as a probability of different effects from one cause.

@JMac Exactly, about QM: In the Copenhagen Interpretation, just because a particle was observed to have a particular spin, does not imply that there were fixed causes for that observation - it was probabilistic.  OTOH, if, for every observation, one were guaranteed to be able to trace a modus-ponens implication all the way down the stack of turtles to obtain the observation you just observed, that seems not very distinct from determinism to me.  Viz. "I observed spin up, and upon further inquiry this was implied by the previous state, which was implied by the previous state, which..."

Logics, like theories, are a component part of our best attempts to describe the universe. Logics cannot tell the universe how it should behave.

Your question hinges on the words "true in the world", and you specifically mention deductive logic. Deductive logic has a special place because it is differenciated from all other kinds of logic (i.e., inductive or abductive logic, which are more heuristic in nature) in that it is mathematically precise and, well, logical - it contains no methods that lead to a probabilistic answer.
With these premises of your question, you throw out the concept of "defeasibility", which is the concept that makes the greater part of all actual human logic fallible.
The way you ask your question, the answer is "yes": if your premises are true, really really true, with nothing missed or misinterpreted, and you then perform deductive logic, and the logic system your are using is valid in, or applicable to, or compatible with the world (as part of your premise), then any of your conclusions are necessarily also true.
If the conclusions were not all true, then either your premises were wrong (which they weren't as part of your requirements); or your logic system, logic rules or however you would call it would be wrong (as relating to the world). You do not specifically formulate this as a premise in your question, but you need to imply that for the question to make sense.
To take everything down to earth: in reality, no logic system and no system of premises is infallible because:

Knowing all relevant premises, and being certain that they are correct, sufficient and consistent is not possible in general.
Knowing whether any given sufficiently complex system of logic is compatible with how the universe "really" works is also generally impossible (and as a side note, for any sufficiently complex system of logic, Gödel has taught us that it is either incomplete or inconsistent - so it is hopeless).


But why is answer really a "yes"? As the Tortoise said to Achilles, she is not "under any logical necessity to accept Z as true".


It is a basic principle of correct logical implication that a true
proposition has only true consequences: Implication it truth
conserving. Hence the answer to your title question is: Yes, the conclusions of a  true premise are also true.

But it is also a basic principle that logic does not amplify the
domain of true propositions, logic is not truth generating.
And logic does not identify the rules of the universe, i.e. the laws of
nature.

At best, one can discuss whether our thinking follows the rules of
logic. But this approach poses the questions: Which logic? There are
several different axiomatized caluculi of logic.




Is the universe metaphysically "obliged" to comply with (deductive) logic?

What you are describing is quite similar to the way the ancient Greeks thought about science.  A good example of this kind of thing is emission theory: the idea that rays (or something) emanate from the eyes to create the sense of sight.  This idea might seem silly to us now, but it follows logically from premises that were believed to be true and was considered true but some of the greatest geniuses of antiquity.
The problem with the theory is that it is not true.  It turns out that the universe is not metaphysically obliged to comply with that logic and/or the premises we create.
The way modern science works is related but different.  I kind of think of it as the same idea but flipped on its head.  We come up with logical arguments which have real world (universe) conclusions.  We then attempt to determine if those conclusions align with observable reality.  If they do (or come close) we take that as evidence that the logical argument and its premises are correct.

+1 "The problem with the theory is that it is not true. It turns out that the universe is not metaphysically obliged to comply with that logic and/or the premises it follows from." Bad premises lead to bad arguments.

@JD True. I'm not sure I completely got this across, but I think it's a much deeper philosophical concept. In theory, we can come up with the correct premises but only by evaluating their conclusions.  In other words, the good premises are derived from the conclusions, not the other way around.  I can't think of any other way we would have discovered quantum mechanics, for example.

Absolutely well put. In science explanatory inference aka inference to best explanation is more important and that's never definitive at all.

You ask:

If a set of premises is true in the world, and we rigorously apply logic to those premises to reach a conclusion, will that conclusion necessarily also be true in the world?

No. First, one can rigorously apply logic poorly or wrong. Valid inferences do not entail sound argument and there is no way to guarantee a truth of a premise cognitively. One classic reason that logic fails is that human reason is defeasible (SEP). By simply lacking another true and relevant premise, we may still get a weak or wrong argument. What we don't know can have bearing on predicting how the world works.
Second, most reason is not modeled with deductive logic, and thus conclusions are not guaranteed from premises. The world is a complex place and regularities and patterns are not as common as might be desired. Inductive reasoning does not bring the certainty that deductive patterns of reasoning bring.
Third, abductive reasoning  sometimes also called inference to best explanation or simply explanatory inference is a form of reasoning from conclusion to premises. Thus, sometimes we take as our starting point propositions that are premises that are contextually speaking what we want to conclude in our argument and then divine the appropriate "premises" and argument to get there. This too does not guarantee certainty in the same way deduction does.
On the whole, then, these facts about reason lead many epistemologists to embrace a position called fallibilism (IEP). From the article:

Fallibilism is the epistemological thesis that no belief (theory, view, thesis, and so on) can ever be rationally supported or justified in a conclusive way. Always, there remains a possible doubt as to the truth of the belief. Fallibilism applies that assessment even to science’s best-entrenched claims and to people’s best-loved commonsense views.


"Second, most reason is not modeled with deductive logic" - You seem to be making an exception for deductive logic. Why? Does the world conform to deductive logic?

Deductive logic is exceptional by virtue that it preserves truth without exception; historically, many thinkers have idolized it. It is, however, also exceptional because it is limited in its scope.

"Deductive logic is exceptional by virtue that it preserves truth without exception" - But how do  we know that this holds true always in the real world? Inductively? Why would the real world be obligated to "respect" deductive logic?

It doesn't. Some deductions fail. Deduction as a logical aspect of language is an ideal meant to model outcomes that are certain in the real world. Consider gravity. An object released from a height will be pulled towards the center of the earth ceteris paribus. So, the argument is a reflection of the state of affairs. If I release an object from a height, it will fall. I released an object from a height. Therefore, the object fell. The universe doesn't force the language to work; the language and logic model the physical world...

Now, if the question is why does deduction do that, then the question is that deductive logic is a property of physical systems of computation. For instance, the syllogism is: Socrates is in the ktichen. The kitchen is in the house. Therefore, Socrates is in the kitchen. This can be constructed with a Turing machine to reflect the following formalism -> X in Y. Y in Z. Therefore X in Z. How that works can also be understood in terms of the lambda calculus.

I think this does not answer the question whether a conclusion reached by deductive logic reached from premises that are “true in the world” is also true in the world, and why that would be so. It rather just says only other, fallible kinds of logic are used in real-world applications.  While that might be true, it doesn’t answer the questions about deductive reasoning.

"one can rigorously apply logic poorly or wrong" No; the definition of rigor is that you're applying the logical rules correctly. "most reason is not modeled with deductive logic, and thus conclusions are not guaranteed from premises" Not relevant, because OP didn't ask about "most" reason, he asked about deductive logic.

@11684 I answered the question I quoted, which was the main question.

@causative "the definition of rigor is that you're applying the logical rules correctly" That sounds like your personal definition, though can you provide a source? Let me give you an example why your definition doesn't work. Andrew Wiles, before he submitted a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem that was deemed correct submitted one that contained an error. No one accused Wiles first proof of lacking rigor. According to MW's definition of rigor: ": strict precision : exactness" What you are doing is confusing precision and accuracy...

what you are advocating for your definition of rigor is accuracy. See https://asana.com/resources/accuracy-vs-precision .

@JD Rigor in mathematics is a special concept you won't find in Merriam-Webster. Half of undergrad math is learning how to be mathematically rigorous. Yes, a proof that contains an error (such as Andrew Wiles' first proposed proof) is not rigorous. Essentially, a rigorous proof is one that could in principle be translated into a valid deduction in formal logic. ("Valid" is also a special term in logic which you aren't using right in your answer.) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170221/what-exactly-is-mathematical-rigor

Wasn't in the Oxford dictionary. Best I could find was this: https://library.fiveable.me/key-terms/history-science/mathematical-rigor No mention of being error-free as a necessary condition though obviously rigor helps reduce error.

@JD That looks like a grade-school education site, although it does at least mention "strict adherence to logical reasoning" which implies correctness. Wolfram MathWorld is a trusted source for mathematics. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rigorous.html

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If a set of premises is true in the world, and we rigorously apply logic to those premises to reach a conclusion, will that conclusion necessarily also be true of the world?
I am going to say Yes. It is precisely this reasoning, for example, that led to the discovery of the planet Neptune. Given what was known about the planet Uranus at the time, its orbit could be predicted. But Uranus was not where it was supposed to be.
Something had to explain the oddities in Uranus’s orbit. The likely orbit and general specifications of the unknown planet were worked out. When that part of the sky was visible again, astronomers took a look. And there it was! Once the math was done, the new planet Neptune was easy to find.
And there you have it: (1) a set of premises which is true in the world, (2) rigorously applied logic to those premises to reach a conclusion, and (3) a conclusion necessarily also true of the world.

So would you say that the universe is inherently logical, and that logic was a discovery rather than an invention?

The planet Neptune wasn't discovered by deductive logic. There were any number of possible explanations for the apparent irregularities in Uranus' orbit, with another planet being only the most likely one. For example, another explanation (unlikely) would be that Newton's law of gravitation needed amendment in some way that would account for the irregularities - in much the same way that MOND (MOdified Newtonian Dynamics) has been proposed more recently as an alternative to dark matter. The discovery was induction, not deduction.

We don't know what premises are true in the world exactly.  Mathematicians build theories that attempt to closely model what goes on out there.  Thus, the theory of the real line was developed in an attempt to model a line in physical space.  The content of the Cantor-Dedekind postulate is the asserted validity of such a correspondence.  Formalisations of set theory such as the Zermelo-Fraenkel theory (ZF) were developed with an eye to guarantee the uniqueness of the real line.  The Axiom of choice was added to ZF, to form the theory ZFC, so as to accommodate certain principles that seemed plausible.
However, eventually it turned out that such a theory (ZFC) has logically inescapable consequences ("conclusions") that can no longer be described as "true in the world", such as the Banach-Tarski paradox, which asserts that a unit ball can be broken up into 5 "pieces" and those pieces reassembled into a pair of unit balls.  Most observers (including physicists) would have difficulty being convinced that such a conclusion is true in the world.
This corroborates the observation that I made at the outset, that mathematicians can only seek to model what goes on out there, without a claim to absolute precision/truth.
To summarize: while we can't know what premises are true in the world, we can document a situation where some initially plausible premises logically lead to markedly less plausible conclusions.

So I'd like to throw out an idea I've heard: That the world may have been built upon math and logic, rather than math and logic being intrinsic to it.
I've heard a Christian philosopher throw out this idea, and I'm not sure I fully understand it, but I find it intriguing.  He was talking about the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in the world, such as in the sciences.  He said God may have built the universe on a blueprint of mathematics and logic.  If that's the case, if I understood it correctly, it wouldn't be so much that logic and math are an "intrinsic" to the universe per se, but that math and logic work so well because nature was built upon them, as faithfully upon a set of plans.  And if that's true, it seems like that would align quite well with how Solomon describes the relationship between the world and "wisdom" (of which logic and math are subsets): "The Lord by wisdom hath founded the earth; by understanding hath he established the heavens." (Proverbs 3:19)
UPDATE: Per request below by @JoWehler, I was able to find the following paper by William Lane Craig which outlines this idea: God and the Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics.  He goes through four viewpoints: nontheistic realist, theistic realist, nontheistic antirealist, theistic antirealist.  Here is my brief summary of each, in this paper, for explaining the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics:

Nontheistic realist: "Happy coincidence," "actually very counterintuitive"
Theistic realist: "God has fashioned the world on the structure of the mathematical objects."
Nontheistic antirealist: When pressed on the highly complex effectiveness, there is "no  explanation as to why" on antirealism.
Theistic antirealist: "God has created it according to a certain blueprint that He had in mind. There are any number of blueprints He might have chosen."


+1 God the Designer has used CADD.

@PeterRankin You quote an anonymous philosopher "throwing out" a certain idea. Could you please support the idea with some philosophical argument, beyond just quoting a religious text which aligns with this idea? Thanks.

Good idea @JoWehler, I found a relevant  link and summarized the basic argument.

William Lane Craig's arguments for nontheists seem very weak; they seem like strawmen to me.  Couldn't it simply be the inverse of what he proposes?  We built math on the blueprint of nature.  If "nature was built using math as a blueprint" counts as an explanation for the theist antirealist, the inverse seems like a valid argument for the nontheist antirealist.  It explains "why" as much as William Lane Craig's argument does.

@JMac I might need to think about that some more, and this is all a bit above my head, but could he respond that the difference is in how remarkably internally consistent advanced math is, while remaining applicable?  I.e., if the world were a junkyard mess underneath, we couldn't expect a such a neat framework to be abstracted over it?  And if the world is so mathematically "neat" by nature, allowing such clean abstraction, would the question remain, Why is nature thus?

It also seems like I may have heard of advanced theoretical math straying out of empirically observable verification for a while, only to end up discovering something highly practical at the end of the quest, seeming to indicate that math is somehow more than simply an abstraction built on top of nature?  I can't remember the details though, I may have to check if that's true...

WLC has had the Atheist Realist position explained in full detail to him more than once, he simply refuses to listen to it. He is a dishonest interlocutor with no apparent interest in the actual position of other disputants. His entire schtick seems to be to plug whatever random thing people are talking about into his directed logic, and to stick to his script even when the people he's quoting stand up to refute him. I'd be careful about relying on such a dishonest source for anything of substance.

Be very careful about what it means to be "true of the world". Often when you unpack carefully-framed deductions, they turn out to be as much statements about how we must describe the world, as they are statements about the world.
So for example if we take the syllogism, "all men are mortal / Socrates is a man / therefore Socrates is mortal": this does not contain any information whatsoever about the implications of being mortal. Depending on the context in which the syllogism is used, it might merely deduce that if we apply the label "man" to Socrates, then we necessarily must also apply the label "mortal" to Socrates. So, it's "true in the world" that "mortal" is a word we must use to describe Socrates. What a "Socrates" is, and what "mortal" means, don't enter into it.
The Universe is not so much metaphysically obliged to comply with logic, as logicians are professionally obliged to redefine "mortal" as necessary to conform to the observed behaviour of Socrates. Or perhaps to withdraw "all men are mortal" as an axiom. The fact that we can even conceive of withdrawing that axiom means that the axiom may not be "true in the world". If it turns out not to be, then the Universe doesn't bear responsibility for our mistakes of observation. Regardless of our syllogism, Socrates can still die or not die as the Universe pleases.
What logic does, is tell us what observations require us to revise our premises. This is the contrapositive to the implication you asked about: you asked, "if the premises are all true, is the conclusion necessarily true". The scientific method relies rather heavily on that contrapositive: "if the conclusion is false, then one or more of the premises is false". So yes, the implication is correct and (with apologies to the positivists) its contrapositive is correct.
That said, it is perhaps astonishing that we can find quite simple rules for manipulating mathematical symbols, that allow predicting the Universe to very good accuracy. To all intents and purposes, the Universe in fact does behave logically, at least in enough contexts to really matter. One can try to account for this by saying that a prerequisite for "intelligence" is to develop a means to predict the Universe. Perhaps if we hadn't evolved modes of thought that "work", we couldn't have evolved the ability to be astonished one way or the other.

"...astonishing that we can find quite simple rules for manipulating mathematical symbols, that allow predicting the  Universe to very good accuracy." If the Universe - and the rules that underly it - are emergent from reasonably simple precursors/substrate/whatever we'd expect that reasonably simple math could describe those emergent phenomena. Much as the math of the Mandelbrot set (iteration on an equation with 2 terms) is simple but produces interestingly complex results. I guess if it were created then there'd be some mild surprise, but God can choose simple. But astonishment? Nah.

I agree with the "checked" answer, but would emphasize its constraint

and the logic system your are using is valid in, or applicable to, or compatible with the world

In particular, there's no logical system whose rules of inference are applicable to everything in the world. Consider
    a=>b & a=>c   .==>.   a=>b&c
I'd guess you'd accept that. But it's not universally applicable.
For example, consider a vending machine that sells, say,
coke for a dollar and also candy for a dollar.
Let's model the vending machine by writing that as   $=>coke & $=>candy.  
But then, contrary to our rule of inference,   $=/=>coke&candy   because the dollar (the premise), gets "used up" when buying (proving) either coke or candy (the conclusion).
That's called "resource awareness", incorporated in the rules of inference for linear logic (where "used up" from our example is called "discharged") and for various other substructural logics. So we need some such resource-aware logic, rather than classical logic, to accurately model vending machines. Many physical systems in the world are resource aware, aka conservation, thus requiring this kind of logic.

"Let's model the vending machine by writing that as   $=>coke" -- surely we shouldn't do that without defining the symbol $? Doing so would reveal the problem. If we interpret the implication as, "I have a dollar => I can get a coke", then the conclusion "I have a dollar => (I can get a coke) AND (I can get a candy)" is true provided we're careful to distinguish that from a different statement, "I can get a coke and a candy".

I mean, I'm not saying that formalising this resource-aware logic isn't useful, but I think I am saying it's just regular logic applied to a resource-aware domain of discourse :-)

@SteveJessop John's point is that the vending machine transforms a dollar into a coke and it also transforms a dollar into candy, but it does not transform a dollar into coke and candy. Classical logic is not well-suited to reasoning about resource-bound interaction like this without bringing in additional theory. Linear logic differs from classical logic by lacking some of its structural features, including the monotonicity and idempotency of entailment.

@Bumble Thanks. Yeah, as per your comment below the original question, " Logics cannot tell the universe how it should behave." The particular universe of discourse pretty much determines any applicable logic.

Even under assumptions that

You know all there is to know in the world
Your logic is fully correct

(and these are some big fat assumptions here),
there is still another factor that should be considered:
A whole could be more than just a sum of its parts.
In the original question, logic "in the world" is as it applies to parts of the world. Logic "of the world" is as it applies to the world as a whole.
This is not necessarily the same (although in many cases it is).
However, if someone claims that for a specific whole, logic gives different results than when applied to its parts, then the burden of proof that this whole behaves differently from its parts is on him.
He/she would have to prove that it is indeed so, and how and why it is so, before it could be accepted that the results of a logical process for the whole should be different than when it's applied to its separate parts.
Here's an interesting example with the sum and parts:
Take all the atoms of the same elements and quantity as are in an adult human body. Dump them on a bed.
Knowing all the laws of physics and chemistry, and having God's own supercomputer, you could, theoretically, calculate what will these atoms do - and it wouldn't be much, maybe a few chemical reactions and that's that, they would just sit there.
But the whole - the human - will get up, and play music, start a lawsuit, go into politics, or commit a crime.
If it was just the logic as it applies to atoms, is the human responsible for the crime? Not any more than a rock that, due to erosion and gravity, falls on someone's head, or two chemicals that start a reaction and make a fire.
But we do hold people responsible, which means we think that they have the option to choose to do (or not do) this or that.
Atoms don't have that option. So where is the difference?
Either the whole is substantially different from the sum of its parts, or there is a "part" here, present in a live human, that we don't know of and don't quite understand.
